# ARM assembly comparing two characters (ascii)

Tags: assembly, arm

```
test:
    ldr r0, [r1, #4]
    bl printf

    ldr r2, [r1, #4]
    ldrb r0, [r2], #1

    cmp r0, #32
    beq test
```

#32 is the decimal ascii code of space

the code is compile by using

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc a.s -T generic-hosted.ld
```

then running with

```
arm-none-eabi-run a.out "abcde"
arm-none-eabi-run a.out " bcde"
```

I suppose that the first command would print out 'abcde' once, the second one with space should print out ' bcde' twice. But i get both printing once, what is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

printf may modify r0, r1, r2, r3, and r12.

You will need to either used a call preserved register (and restore it before returning), or save the value on the stack.

Answer (score 0):

[Timothy Baldwin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52991938/arm-assembly-comparing-two-characters-ascii#52994018) is accurate but I thought I'd expand on it a little.  The ARM Application Binary Interface (ABI), and in particular the [procedure call standard](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0042f/IHI0042F_aapcs.pdf), defines how each register is treated across procedure call boundaries.

In summary, `r0-r3` are used for argument and return value passing, and must be preserved by the *caller* along with the 'intra procedure call scratch register' `r12`.  All other general-purpose registers must be preserved by the *callee*.  So if you're writing your own functions in assembly language you must push any of `r4-r11` that you use, in addition to `lr` (`r14`) if you call any other functions, and you must ensure that your usage of the stack is 'balanced' so that `sp` (`r13`) has the same value on exit as on entry.

Most compilers (at least with optimisations disabled) will generate code that meets these requirements by moving any function arguments out of `r0-r3` right at the start, just after pushing the callee-preserve registers; by moving any return value into `r0` just before return; and by using `r0-r3` only for passing arguments to and from called functions during the function's execution.

Additionally, across functions in different object files (i.e. in different source files) the stack must be 8-byte aligned, and so it's a good habit to maintain 8-byte alignment at all times because it's easy to do and it's free (for reasons related to the cache).  To do this, make sure every interaction with the stack (every `PUSH` and `POP`) involves an even number of registers, pushing and popping additional registers if necessary to make up an even number.